# fixed-width column format for SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

I have googled this and found nothing useful. The requirement is to produce a flat file in a format specified by position; e.g. field one is 30 characters, field 2 is 8 characters, so field 3 starts at column 39...

In SSIS, this was trivial.

I need a way for a user to go to the SSRS report server, run the report in a visual way (e.g. a table, also very easy to do), and then have an option to download into this required fixed width format.

Can I create a custom download format that would basically be "no delimiters"?

The data is selected in a way that each field is a fixed width columnn, i.e.

```
cast(ISNULL([13],'') as char(8)) as [13],
cast(ISNULL([14],'') as char(8)) as [14],
cast(ISNULL([15],'') as char(8)) as [15],
```

Another option we have used is to concatenate into a single text column, i.e.

```
cast(ISNULL([13],'') as char(8)) +
cast(ISNULL([14],'') as char(8)) +
cast(ISNULL([15],'') as char(8)) as bigwidesinglefield
```

but that has not worked for export either.

SSIS is generally the solution, but in this case, I need an on-demand file so an end user can perform a manual extract and then send the file to a regulatory reporting entity. I prefer not to just drop the output from SSIS on a file share somewhere because the data is confidential.

Comment: Rather than trying to make SSRS do something it's not really designed for, I think I'd look into one of the several ways to allow users to execute an SSIS package on demand. Then the only challenge is how fancy to make the UI if you decide to build one.

Comment: why not create a custom export format, like the CSV one on the report server, only not specify the delimiter? Call it what you want and get your end users to export using that extension instead? (save as -> your custom format)

Comment: re custom format, no delimiter...can we ensure that fields consisting of 10 spaces, get saved as 10 spaces and that there are no qualifiers introduced when SSRS thinks it needs a qualifier? I think I have tried this before and the output didn't always come through as fixed width.

Comment: what you could do is Pad each column with NCHAR(0x00A0) instead of ' '. this should(in theory) keep it as fixed width. give it a go and see what happened.

Comment: Create two reports. The first is the pretty one the user sees. The seconds will have a dataset where everything in the row is padded with spaces, essentially a single column report. Put a action on a textbox that opens the url to the second report and passes the same parameter values in automatically with CSV as the render format. So then it's just view pretty report, click link, get single column CSV.